# tabulator get column from custom column titleFormatter

Tags: tabulator

I have a custom function that hides/shows columns in my tabulator.  The column I click on is supposed to hide and several other columns are shown.  I have this function working correctly from onclick on an object in a custom cell formatter, but I would like to call it from clicking on the column header. It works except that I can't seem to get a handle of the column I clicked on from column header in order to hide the column.

I'm trying to get the column object and pass it to my function so I can hide that column while I show the others. I'm open to other ways to do this.

this works (cell formatter)

```
var showForecastCell = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
   ...
   span.onclick = function(){showForecast(cell.getColumn())};
   return span
}
```

this doesn't work (column titleFormatter)

```
var showForecastHeader = function(t,e,o,i,n){
   ...
   span.onclick = function(){showForecast(t.getColumn())};
   return span
}
```

Is there any way to pass the column object from clicking on the column header? otherwise, if there is a simpler way to hide the column after clicking on the header, I am open to suggestions.  I must admit that javascript isn't my strongest language and if I am overlooking something basic, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/7xuh84oc/14/) it hides all other columns except the one you click

for Column call backs you can check documentation [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/callbacks#column) and [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/columns#visibility)

```
  const hideAllButThis = function(e, column) {
  const showField = column._column.field;
  const columns = column._column.table.columnManager.columns;
  for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (columns[i].field !== showField) {
      table.hideColumn("" + columns[i].field + "")
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hmm.  I wasn't intending to make the entire column header onclick go to my function, just a button I was putting in the column header with a custom titleformatter.  I see how that would work though. I ended up passing the field name in text and doing a table.getColumn using the field name.  it seems like an extra step, but that's the only way I could find to do it.  I'll think about whether clicking the entire header would work for my users.

Comment: @JaredH Didn't understand, if you still have an issue please post a JSfiddle thanks